# How do I detect when a user hits enter as input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

A part of a script I am writing deals with getting a file to pass into other aspects of my terminal application. Here is my code:

```
def get_file():

custom_data_folder = input("Name of custom data directory - " +
                           "Hit ENTER to use default: ")
file_name = input("File name: ")
default_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('data', file_name))
custom_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(custom_data_folder, file_name))

if custom_data_folder == '\n':
    return(default_path if os.path.exists(default_path) is True 
                     else "The file or path does not exist.")
else:
    return(custom_path if os.path.exists(custom_path) is True 
                       else "The file or path does not exist.")
```

My script assumes a file is in a directory called "data", but I wanted to provide an option of a entering a custom directory where a file could be.

The problem comes when I try to use "/n" newline to detect whether a user hit enter or not. It seems to just return the working -and the files in it- directory instead of the "data" directory and its files I am aiming for.

How do I go about detecting whether the user hit enter or not?

I am working in linux / ubuntu. A solution for that platform alone is nice, but I would prefer a multi-platform solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user presses enter without typing anything into the input, it will return an empty string. You could change your if statement to the following.

```
if custom_data_folder == '':
```